# Tastypie recognizes logged in user as AnonymousUser

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I deployed my Django app to a remote server, but tastypie doesn't recognize a logged in user on the remote server.

I have a tastypie resource that filters all objects that belong to the currently logged in user:

```
  def apply_authorization_limits(self, request, object_list):
    return object_list.filter(user=request.user)
```

When I try to do a GET request on the endpoint for the objects, I get the following error:

```
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'AnonymousUser
```

I am guessing because the login did not work correctly?

Or did it? On a template page, I have the following code:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  Logged in as <strong>{{ user.username }}</strong>
  <a href="/users/logout">Logout</a>
{% else %}
  <a href="/users/signup">Signup</a>
  <a href="/users/login">Login</a>
{% endif %}
```

And the code correctly displays the user's username (which means that the user has been authenticated). What could be happening? On my local server, I am able to do all HTTP requests to the tastypie API successfully, and I am not known as an AnonymousUser, but on my remote server, I am known as AnonymousUser to Tastypie

Edit:
When I have a print statement printing out request.user in any view, I get the correct logged in user. When I have a print statement in my Tastypie api.py that prints out request.user, then I am known as AnonymousUser. Why would I be known as AnonymousUser to Tastypie but not to the rest of the application?

Edit:
I am using the following authentication:

```
authentication = Authentication()
```

If I changed the authentication to ApiKeyAuthentication, then I would have to post the username and api key on each GET/POST request to a Resource. The problem with doing that is that I would have to create a new intermediate view which queried for the username and the view and then did the GET/POST to the Tastypie endpoint. Is there another solution for this?
The second way is to embed the username and apikey into the webapp and get JS to grab those values and add them to the GET/POST querystring, but this could lead to a security issue. It would be a security issue because a user could pretend to be another user if they had their username and api key.

Comment: How do you make requests to `tastypie`? Is it AJAX or something else? What exact URLs are you requesting when is logged in and when is anonymous? Are they on exactly the same domain?

Comment: I make them through AJAX. The URLS are the same if the user is logged in or if the user is anonymous. Tastypie handles the case where a user is logged in or not logged in. The requests are made from the same domain.

Comment: I'm almost sure there's something that prevents sessionid sookie to reach the server. Take a look on your requests in Firebug (or web inspector), do they include sessionid cookie?

Comment: Please post your resource code. This behavior is dependent on the value of Meta.authentication

Comment: @IssacKelly I added the resource code's authentication method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: APIKeyAuth: It's as much of an issue as if another user gets the username and password, or the session id over an insecure connection.

Second: If you want to use session based authentication (it only works in the browser, for currently logged in users) You would need to create your own authentication backend, which is detailed in the docs at http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authentication_authorization.html#implementing-your-own-authentication-authorization

Scroll up a bit from there though, and read the nasty warning about the Authentication method that you have chosen.

Comment: How would I roll out Authentication based on sessions? I believe that sessions do not automatically contain information about the currently logged in user(or does it?) That means I would have to access request.user from my custom authentication. But, I wouldn't be able to do that because when I try to access request.user from my custom authentication backend, I get back AnonymousUser.

Comment: Nevermind, I just added the username and api key inside of Javascript tags, so I could access it throughout the rest of the page.